# Wanted: ASP.NET control to view/print PDF, TIFF, possibly more?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, tiff

I'm looking for an asp.NET control that will allow for viewing and printing of a pdf and TIFF within a web form.  I'm willing to use more than 1 control if needed (1 control for pdf, 1 for Tiff, show and hide based on file extension), but I have not been able to find a good Tiff viewer.

Files are stored on our LAN in a shared folder, and this application is an intranet site.

Open source / free licensing preferred, but I'm willing to look at paid options as well.

Comment: What are you aiming for with this viewer? Why not let the users OS display the file with it's native viewer?

Comment: Extremely non-technical user base.  I want them to be able to do everything they need on one webform.  Other windows open up and they get confused.  View/print from browser.  Nothing more is needed.

Comment: What you're actually doing is giving the user more than one way to achieve a goal (the goal is to print a PDF or a TIFF), some users may already know how to do this and now you're the source of confusion by changing it. To make users more comfortable with your application you shouldn't introduce new UI concepts. If you find that your users can't open a PDF with Adobe or whatever then you'd probably be better to provide training to those users and spend your development time adding more unique selling points to your app. How non-technical do you mean, whats your target audience?

Comment: Do you have a suggestion on how to answer my question?  I'm not looking for different ways of accomplishing, I'm looking for guidance on this method.

Comment: My suggestion would be to just let the OS handle PDF and TIFF using the users application of choice. It doesn't strictly answer your question but that's what I'd try to convince my manager to le me do so I could spend my time elsewhere.

Comment: We're not here to to argue managerial issues.  This is a technical forum.  If someone can solve the technical problem, a post is welcome.  Otherwise I'm confused by posts which attempt to force a user requirements change.  Makes no sense.

Comment: If you look again I commented on your question rather than posted an answer. Your suggested solution to your non-problem makes no sense. If you want to benifit from the experience of other developers then ask here; if you just want someone to tell you the name of an ASP.NET control, why not google it yourself and save everybody some time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm in total agreement with @BenCr on this.

Viewing PDFs is an extremely common thing to do.  This isn't a "technical" issue by any stretch.

It sounds like you have some type of faxing solution in place that is creating these documents.  Most likely multi-page TIFF and PDFs.

If this is the case you might want to just convert the TIFFs to PDFs to begin with and run everything through Adobe's pdf reader.  Every online fax solution does this.

Comment: Any suggestion on how to do the conversion from TIFF to PDF?  Is this something I can do when the file is requested?

Comment: @MAW74656: Absolutely.  See the following: http://forums.asp.net/t/1348035.aspx/1

Comment: Perhaps I'll just go all the way and convert all the TIFFs.

Comment: Have you used this method from your link?  Is it reasonably performant?

Comment: @MAW74656: The last time I had to do this type of thing was a LONG time ago.  However, there are a lot of people on this site using PDFSharp.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.alternatiff.com/ is one of the viewers that I've seen used for this type of viewing of tiffs.

Comment: I've used it. It works well. It has acrobat style controls for viewing multi-page tiff images.

Comment: This would require installation on all user stations, it looks like.  This is part of what I want to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a free licence of [ABCPDF](http://www.websupergoo.com/products.htm#pd) (provided you link back to their site) which will do the conversion from TIFF to PDF for you as per @Chris Lively 's suggestion.

It'll also do conversion from PDF to TIFF if you decide to do things backwards.

It makes sense to present the content in a common format.  If you wanted to you can embed the PDF in the browser to create the 'seamless' experience you're looking for using something like [PDFObject](http://pdfobject.com/).

As @BenCr says though, PDF is a really common format and the tools already exist to open and work with them, so introducing new ways to perform existing tasks could actually end up complicating matters unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0):

You could try http://issuu.com/ and they appear to have a API too if you want to go that deep.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is practical in my case, files are stored on the LAN, cannot upload.

Answer (score 0):

If you can mess about with mime types -- mainly by making the .tiff files expose an application/pdf mimetype -- you should be able to get acrobat to open TIFF files directly by effectively fooling the browser to open TIFF files with acrobat. Then all you need is a trusty old iframe to get you familiar UI with print buttons.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit?  What change to mime types do I need to make?

Comment: Updated the answer a bit to answer your question.

Comment: I like the end product being visually the same for pdf vs tiff.  But I'm unfamililar with modifying tiff files in that way.  "Making the .tiff files expose an application/pdf mimetype..."  Where can I start?  Do you know of a good tutorial?

Comment: Not sure if there is a specific tutorial, but most web servers allow one to map file extensions to given mimetypes if you want to serve off the filesystem or to specify your own mimetype if you are serving via your own file handler of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

We used the the [Seadragon control](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/seadragon/seadragon.aspx) to do this.  I think it was an overkill and we should have just rolled our own -- would have been cheaper than integrating it.  TIFFs and PDFs are converted to PNG on the server side.  I don't think you can do better than that, especially with PDFs (assuming you don't want to use Acrobat Reader to display them).  Convert PDFs to PNG using Xpdf/Poppler.

Answer (score 0):

How about using [Google Docs Viewer](https://docs.google.com/viewer)?

EDIT: Probably not working, since the viewer has to read the document from your URL; when it's on the Intranet, this won't work.